# NIC name from PIP in azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to fetch NIC name from Public IP.I am stuck at fetching NIC name from IP configuration.

I've IP configuration of PIP as:

/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/NetworkWatcherRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/testnic/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1

$ip.IpConfiguration.Id.tostring().Substring($ip.IpConfiguration.Id.ToString().LastIndexOf('/')+1)

I expect output as 'testnic' but it's giving me output 'ipconfig1'

Comment: Do you mean you're getting the wrong value from your `$...Substring()...` line? If `$ip.IpConfiguration.Id` is the value you posted above then that's obviously going to return you the string after the final /, i.e. ipconfig1, because that's what your Substring and LastIndexOf do. Or did you mean you expected `$ip.IpConfiguration.Id` to give you 'testnic'?

Comment: Yes after final / I will get ipconfig1. But I can't understand how to play with indexof() to get 'testnic'. @Rup

Comment: `$ip.IpConfiguration.Id.tostring().Split('/')[-3]`

Comment: Thanks @iRon it actually worked.Could you share me a link which can provide me info on such functions for strings.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ip.IpConfiguration.Id.tostring().Split('/')[-3]
```

[`Split('/')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) is a .Net method of the [`String` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) which *returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array*.

You might also use the PowerShell [`-Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) operator for this which has some more features that do not apply to this question:

```
($ip.IpConfiguration.Id.tostring() -Split '/')[-3]
```

`[-3]` is not a part of the method but an index in the array returned by the split method. *Negative numbers count from the end of the array. For example, "-1" refers to the last element of the array.* See: [Reading an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6#reading-an-array)